# Eclipse plugin m2e not working in Luna 4.4 (release June 25, 2014)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

After installing m2e using "Install New Software..." from the Help drop-down it wouldn't show in the context menu or as import options. Other plug-ins like EGit do.

I downloaded it from here:
[Eclipse downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/)

Comment: Did you try restarting eclipse?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I just installed the "M2E for Juno and newer" from the Marketplace and it does not work like it does on Kepler. Today is June 25th, the day Luna came out. Figured out that you just need to install "Maven tools 0.2.0" from the marketplace.  That solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Kepler version, it has maven included by default:

[Eclipse Kepler](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2)

Comment: I'm downloading it and see if it works.

Comment: The point about this question is that Luna came out today and the M2E plugin doesn't work in it.

Answer (score 1):

[This version of Eclipse Luna](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunam7) has Maven plugin by default, try it.

Comment: Not necessary since I found a workaround that works with the official new release of Luna.